# how to zoom in/out map view using double taps+Swipe recognizer (like google maps) for ios

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How to zoom in/out map view using double taps+Swipe recognizer (like google maps)

what is the recognizer to be added to the map view , i'm preferring swift lang.

Thanks,

a preview:

```
@IBOutlet var map: MKMapView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
              super.viewDidLoad()
            map.showsUserLocation = true
            map.delegate = self
            let LongPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "LongPress:")
            LongPress.minimumPressDuration = 1
            LongPress.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
            map.addGestureRecognizer(LongPress)
```

Answer (score 1):

I find a solution. Obviously, it's a panGesture event, but you can't use any gesture to implement, cause the double-tap gesture won't trigger until you leave the screen. So, another way is to override the touchesMoved function in mapView :

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)

    for touch in touches {

        if(touch.tapCount == 2) // tapCount 2 means tap on map twice
        {
            tapPositionY = touch.location(in: self).y // self is the mapView
        }
    }
}
```

tapPositionY is used for storage the position where user touched on screen. So we can know zoom in or zoom out the mapView.

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)

    for touch in touches {

        if(touch.tapCount == 2)
        {

            let positionY = touch.location(in: self).y

            // 0.95 and 1.05 is zoom in/ zoom out parameter. you can change it
            let zoom = positionY - tapPositionY > 0 ? 0.95 : 1.05 


            var region = self.region
            var span = self.region.span                
            span.latitudeDelta = span.latitudeDelta * zoom
            span.longitudeDelta = span.longitudeDelta * zoom
            region.span = span

            self.setRegion(region, animated: false)

            tapPositionY = positionY // storage the position
        }
    }
}
```

setRegion animated must be false, but the same effect. If set true, it will be like delay.

Answer (score -2):

Zoom In/Out functionality is provided by [UIPinchGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPinchGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html).
Double tap - [UITapGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/).

You don't need to implement any of those recognizers on your own except double tap. MKMapView is built on top of the same class as the UIScrollView. And by viewing its protocol you will see available methods. However, MKMapKit overwrites them and you can't assign independent delegate to its inner UIScrollView. But you can overwrite

```
- mapView:regionWillChangeAnimated:
- mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:
```

methods of [MKMapViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/) protocol and manually compare visible rects and zoom levels.

Comment: i know that UIPinchGestureRecognizer is already added to the map to zoom in/out , but i need to add a recognizer that performs the samething by using only one finger (double taps+swipe) you can try this in google maps app then you will understand me .

Answer (score -3):

For double tap you can use this code:

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(doubleTapped))
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)


func doubleTapped() {
    // do your code here
}
```

On [this](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/gesture-recognizer-using-swift) link you can see more gestures.